# Get videos from a facebook page and their length using field expansion using Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have been looking at the field expansion functionality of [graph API from facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/). I tried this approach to get the duration of videos on a facebook page but it does not return my required fields. I have made following attempts to retrieve the required information

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.9/575805779234615/videos?access_token=<my token>&fields=videos.fields(id,length)
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.9/575805779234615/videos?access_token=<my token>&fields=videos{id,length}
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.9/575805779234615/videos?access_token=<my token>&fields=data{id,length}
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.9/575805779234615/videos?access_token=<my token>&fields=posts{id,length}
```

At best, I am able to get back the required fields from facebook i.e `description`, `id`, `last_updated`. Any ideas how I can use this nesting to save some requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're already sending a call to `/videos` you shouldn't need to use field expansion to get the length. Try this:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.9/575805779234615/videos?access_token=<my token>&fields=length,description,id
```